# flexbox align items mess

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i'd like to get  similar effect to my sketch.

https://postimg.org/image/o03qu4tpp/

The man always  should be placed at right bottom corner  of  header. And the  caroussel  should be on  the center/center-left position ( 50% of header height)   .

I added new class (pad4)  to my  header  container, and used flexbox.

```
display: flex;
```

justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;

And now, a man is on  left bottom corner and the text is on top-right  corner.   I don't know how to fix it now. Because when I use margin or padding, nothing happens.

Site :  http://jarmor.webd.pl/designs/kovta/agency2a.html

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

`display: flex` has to be applied to a parent element, so that the children are considered as flex elements. Therefore, you should apply `display: flex; align-items: flex-end;` to your `<header>` element. Then, apply `align-self: center` to the slider container (div.container-fluid.pad4 in your case). The result is following: [image: The result]